# Can a shower head have a back leak?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, walls, shower

I have a shower in the upstairs bathroom and water is leaking through the downstairs ceiling.

Initially I thought it was the caulking around the bathtub, but after redoing it did not fix the problem. I noticed that when the shower is point toward the wall, it rains downstairs, but when it is pointing away from the wall there is no leak.

However there is no hole or broken grout on the wall tiles, and even if there was it would not justify the amount of water falling down.

Any suggestions what could it be?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a few pictures of the shower head area?

Comment: Typically there's a run of pipe in the wall between the valve and the shower head. Quite possibly the force applied when re-aiming the shower head opens a  leak in a bad solder joint.

Comment: @JACK I've updated the question to include photos! thanks

Comment: Make sure that pipe coming through the wall  that the shower head it attached to is tight, pull the cover away from the wall and check for dampness. Make sure the shower head is tight and not spraying water back toward that opening.

Comment: When it is pointing at the wall, is it time to seal your tile those photos don’t really show any detail that I see.

Comment: Point the head in the direction to cause the leak (toward the wall?) but catch the shower water in a bucket. Is there still a leak? If so, the leak is in the wall. Or put some sort of cap in place of the shower head and look for a leak.